# 28 bytes for empty object/class instance?

Tags: java

I did some benchmarks comparing performance of int vs Integer, long vs Long, empty class instance vs class instance with long value.

And I have few questions which I cannot answer myself:

1. why instantiating of empty class or object takes 28 bytes?
2. instantiating of Long object takes 29 bytes, primitive long 8 bytes, so why the difference to empty class is only 1 byte? what kind of optimization is JVM doing?

I used JDK1.6.0_30 on MacOS, and the code is available at 
https://github.com/mousator/benchmarks/blob/master/src/sk/emandem/michal/AutoboxingTypeBenchmark.java
(you can checkout the whole project)

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I wouldn't trust your memory measurement technique.  Just calling `runtime.gc()` doesn't necessarily do anything.  Use a tool like [MemoryMeasurer](http://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/).
2. Arrays incur overhead of their own: typically on the order of 12 bytes; eight for the object header and four for the array length, and then four bytes per array entry for a reference.  (That's on 32-bit VMs.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Louis. I tried MemoryMeasurer, for empty class I'm getting 20 bytes, so 4 bytes as array pointer and 16 for instance (though 16 a bit weird). 

However, the runtime method is interesting since it's producing quite stable measurements - iterative repetition of sequence "invoke GC, measure memory, call code, measure memory, invoke GC" getting same values. 

The only difference in measurements between using runtime and MemoryMeasurer is in empty class and int wrapper (both 25B vs 20B)

Comment: I pressed enter.. So the followed up question is, can I estimate OOME using 20 or 25B?

Comment: Uh.  I wouldn't depend on it.  Much simpler just to try it and see.